# Extjs4 how to use XTemplate in tooltip

Tags: extjs4

I have a chart with tooltip in it, what I exactly want to do is I need to set title for tooltip something like this using XTemplate:

```
tips = { 
    trackMouse: true,
    width: 120,
    height: 23,
    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
        var myTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate('<p> {Value} </p>')
        myTemplate.overwrite(this.title, {
            Value : storeItem.get(Field)
        });
    }
}
```

But it is showing error like 'tagname' is null, can anyone give me solution for this. How can I get div id of that tips and how can I set title for tooltip?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Without XTemplate

```
renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
    this.setTitle(Ext.String.format('<p>{0}</p>', storeItem.get(**title field name**));
}
```

With XTemplate

```
renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
    var tpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<p>', '{Value}', '</p>');

    this.setTitle(tpl.apply({
        Value: storeItem.get(**title field name**)
    }));
}
```

Comment: Working but its too slow :( tooltip ll appear after sometime

Comment: You also can setup [show](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip-cfg-showDelay) and [hide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip-cfg-hideDelay) delays